# Como desabilitar teclas de atalho em um textbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

Tenho um controle do tipo `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` populado no meu formulário e ele possuí algumas validações, como permitir que eu digite apenas números, porém percebi que se eu utilizo a tecla de atalho para colar um texto (`Ctrl + V`), esse campo recebe a informação e eu não gostaria que isso acontecesse.

Existe alguma forma de bloquear esse comportamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de resolver isso é selecionar o controle alterar a opção da propriedade `Shortcuts Enabled` para `False`

[image]